# Is NN saturation always bad?

Tags: neural-networks, supervised-learning

I am trying to analyse the effect of hidden unit saturation (outputting mostly 0 and 1 for sigmoid, and not much in-between) on the neural network training performance, and I feel a bit stuck, theory-wise: who says saturation is necessarily a bad thing? The idea is that a saturated unit can not differentiate much between patterns. However, that is only true if the unit outputs the same value for all signals it receives. What if the unit just turns binary? Of course, a collection of binary units has less information capacity than a collection of continuous non-linear functions... But perhaps binary (saturated) units still have a place and should not necessarily be eliminated? What are your thoughts on the dangers of saturation? And... are there any standard cures besides regularisation?

Comment: I am not sure I understood what you mean. In any case, this paper http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98b.pdf gives you great advice on how to avoid some well-known difficulties when training a NN.

Comment: I am aware of that paper... However, I struggle to find any information regarding saturation specifically.

Comment: Hello Anna, it would help to know a bit about your approach: do you normalize your data? what kind of architecture do you use? is it a standard package or your own implementation? What cost are you trying to minimize? for what problem (classification/regression)?

Comment: Hi juampa. My approach is somewhat basic: I use a NN with a single hidden layer, and I work with both classification and time series prediction problems. The data is not normalised - just scaled to a small interval in the the active range of the activation function. Looking through LeCun's paper referenced above, I realised that normalisation is perhaps in order - I will do it now and see if it makes much of a difference. The implementation is a collaborative effort of my research group, so the code is not mine all through, but I am fluent in it and can easily add any necessary functionality.

Comment: One reason why saturation is considered bad is that it stops gradient propagation: when a unit saturates, the gradients of all weights feeding into that unit become very small (since the sigmoid is almost flat) and thus the backpropagation learning signal vanishes. (This is stated for instance in this article: http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf) However, backpropagation algorithms such as RPROP only make use of the sign of the gradient, so I am not sure whether this applies to them.